# How to hide "failed dependencies" logs on puppet

Tags: puppet

I would like to avoid (or hide at least) "failed dependencies" logs on puppet.

I want to deploy files only if exec requirement are true. It's working but puppet shows a lot of err/warning logs :

```
Error: /usr/bin/test -e /home/USER returned 1 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/Exec[/usr/bin/test -e /home/USER]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/bin/test -e /home/USER returned 1 instead of one of [0]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/Exec[check_ssh_dir]: Dependency Exec[/usr/bin/test -e /home/USER] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/Exec[check_ssh_dir]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/File[/home/USER/.ssh]: Dependency Exec[/usr/bin/test -e /home/USER] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/File[/home/USER/.ssh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/File[/home/USER/.bashrc]: Dependency Exec[/usr/bin/test -e /home/USER] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/File[/home/USER/.bashrc]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/File[/home/USER/.bash_profile]: Dependency Exec[/usr/bin/test -e /home/USER] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/File[/home/USER/.bash_profile]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/File[/home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys]: Dependency Exec[/usr/bin/test -e /home/USER] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Users::Config/File[/home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

Here is my config.pp :

```
class users::config ($user) {

    exec {"/usr/bin/test -e /home/${user}":
    }

    exec {"check_ssh_dir":
        command => '/bin/true',
        onlyif => "/usr/bin/test -e /home/${user}/.ssh",
        require => Exec["/usr/bin/test -e /home/${user}"],
    }

    file {"/home/${user}/.ssh":
        ensure => directory,
        owner   => "${user}",
        group   => "domain users",
        mode    => "700",
        require => Exec['check_ssh_dir'],
    }

    file {"/home/${user}/.bashrc":
        source => [ "puppet:///modules/users/${user}/bashrc", "puppet:///modules/users/basics/bashrc"],
        owner   => "${user}",
        group   => "domain users",
        mode    => "640",
        require => Exec["/usr/bin/test -e /home/${user}"],
    }

    file {"/home/${user}/.bash_profile":
        source => [ "puppet:///modules/users/${user}/bash_profile", "puppet:///modules/users/basics/bash_profile"],
        owner   => "${user}",
        group   => "domain users",
        mode    => "640",
        require => Exec["/usr/bin/test -e /home/${user}"],
    }

    file {"/home/${user}/.ssh/authorized_keys":
        source => [ "puppet:///modules/users/${user}/ssh/authorized_keys", "puppet:///modules/users/basics/ssh/authorized_keys"],
        owner   => "${user}",
        group   => "domain users",
        mode    => "600",
        require => Exec["check_ssh_dir"],
    }
}
```

I'm using puppet 4.3.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to solve my issue thanks to @Artefacto :

I have created a new fact which just list homes :

```
Facter.add(:list_home) do
    setcode do
        Facter::Core::Execution.exec('/bin/ls /home/').split("\n")
    end
end
```

And I have modified my manifest to iterate on each home :

```
class users::config {

    $::list_home.each |String $user| {
        exec {"check_ssh_dir_${user}":
            command => '/bin/true',
            onlyif => "/usr/bin/test -e /home/${user}/.ssh",
        }

        file {"/home/${user}/.ssh":
            ensure => directory,
            owner   => "${user}",
                    group   => "domain users",
                    mode    => "700",
            require => Exec["check_ssh_dir_${user}"],
        }

        file {"/home/${user}/.bashrc":
            source => [ "puppet:///modules/users/${user}/bashrc", "puppet:///modules/users/basics/bashrc"],
            owner   => "${user}",
            group   => "domain users",
            mode    => "640",
        }

        file {"/home/${user}/.bash_profile":
            source => [ "puppet:///modules/users/${user}/bash_profile", "puppet:///modules/users/basics/bash_profile"],
            owner   => "${user}",
            group   => "domain users",
            mode    => "640",
        }

        file {"/home/${user}/.ssh/authorized_keys":
            source => [ "puppet:///modules/users/${user}/ssh/authorized_keys", "puppet:///modules/users/basics/ssh/authorized_keys"],
            owner   => "${user}",
            group   => "domain users",
            mode    => "600",
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have no failed due to dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really possible without using facts or implementing a custom provider. To be sure, with `exec` resources you can do something like this:

```
exec { 'test-user-exists:
    command => '/bin/true',
    onlyif  => "/usr/bin/test -e /home/${user}"
} ~>
exec { 'conditional-command':
    command     => '/usr/bin/my-command',
    refreshonly => true,
}
```

But you won't be able to have conditional `file` resources on the result of the a command. The easiest option is to create a fact. Something like:

```
Facter.add(:avail_users) do
  setcode do
    IO.
      readlines('/etc/passwd').
      map { |x| x.split(':')[0] }
  end
end
```

Then you could check if `$user` was in the array `$::avail_users` in an `if` block. Make sure you don't have `stringify_facts` on.

Comment: I already tried something like the 2 exec commands you posted, but it's the same problem (it was even worst : the exec test was only working for my last "file" section, all others returned errors).

I can't use the /etc/passwd because my users are not defined in (i'm using the AD authentication with winbind, so the only trace I have about my users is their home directories when they log once on the server).

I think I can do something with the fact : check what home directories are present in /home/*.

thanks :)